# grunt - uglify: Uglify to one row code

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm new to grunt using and I'd like to uglify code to 1 row code.
I`m using [This grunt plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify).
Is it possible?

Thanks for help

```
 uglify: {
            prod: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '../addon/js',
                    src: ['imagech.js'],
                    dest: '../addon/js/'
                }]
            }

        },


grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.registerTask('addon-prod', ['jshint','uglify:prod']);
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @DavidKristianLaundav Code updated. This code make uglify, but in 5 rows, i`d like to make only one non wrapped row

Comment: @RohitGupta Code updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uglify` has a default max line length of 32000, which probably causes your wrapping. You can disable it by setting `maxLineLen` to 0 in your grunt options: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#maxlinelen